Write to a Firebird DB using Power Automate
I want write to a Firebird database (.fdb) using Power Automate. How can I make it possible?
I have a table with a list of products with the price in Power Apps. The user can change the price, and I need to update the product with the new price if the user changes it.

Have you checked if Firebird is supported? Or if it has generic ODBC support or something?

Isn't this link the answer? It looks like Power Automation uses OLE DB to access databases.
